# ASP and VBScript - Adding records to database

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

OK, so I have attempted to add some code to an existing ASP web page that connects to an access database for data collection.  The code is supposed to check if the distinct 'modecode' variables in a 'fleet' table match the 'equipment' table.  If 'equipment' modes are missing it adds the ones that are missing.  The issue I am having is that on the first load of the page, it throws an error, but adds the correct records.  Then if you reload the page it displays normally.  The code is below.

EDIT: Is it possible that the error is from not defining every variable in 'Equiment' when I add the new records?

EDIT: The error I get is just a '500 - Internal Server Error' and I'm not sure how to diagnose.

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "vehicles","",""

Dim modeArr()       'array to hold modecodes
Dim i       'array index
Dim needToClickUpdate       'If an Equipment # > than a Fleet #, 
Dim k       'for loop index
needToClickUpdate = ""
'Get the total # of active vehicles by mode from the fleet table.
strFleet = "SELECT Sum(Number) As NumVehPerMode, modecode FROM fleet WHERE MemID=" & Request("MemID") & " And status='A' GROUP BY modecode ORDER BY modecode"
Set rstFleet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstFleet.Open strFleet, conn, 3, 3      
If rstFleet.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rstFleet.MoveFirst 
    Dim TotNumVeh() 'array to hold # vehicles per mode
    Dim TotModLis() 'array with list of modes
    Dim TotModLis2()
    i = 0
    while Not rstFleet.EOF
        Redim Preserve TotNumVeh(i+1)
        TotNumVeh(i) = rstFleet("NumVehPerMode")
        Redim Preserve TotModLis(i+1)
        TotModLis(i) = rstFleet("modecode")
        Redim Preserve TotModLis2(i+1)
        TotModLis2(i) = rstFleet("modecode")
        i = i + 1
        rstFleet.MoveNext
    wend

End If
rstFleet.Close
'This section grabs which modes have equipment records
strEquipmodecheck = "SELECT modecode FROM Equipment WHERE MemID=" & Request("MemID")    & " AND modecode IN ('" & Join(TotModLis, "','") & "') ORDER BY modecode"
rstFleet.Open strEquipmodecheck, conn, 3, 3 
If rstFleet.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rstFleet.MoveFirst 
    Dim n
    Dim m
    Dim Equipmodes()
    Dim MissingModes : Missingmodes = Array()
    Dim isFound
    m = 0
    n = 0
    p = 0
    while Not rstFleet.EOF
        Redim Preserve Equipmodes(m+1)
        Equipmodes(m) = rstFleet("modecode")
        m = m + 1
        rstFleet.MoveNext   
    wend

End If
rstFleet.Close
'This section compares the mode lists from Fleet and Equipment and writes a list of Missing Modes
For m = 0 To UBound(TotModLis2) - 1
    isFound = False
    For n = 0 To UBound(Equipmodes) - 1
        If TotModLis2(m) = Equipmodes(n) Then
            isFound = True
        End If
    Next 'j
    If Not isFound Then
        Redim Preserve MissingModes(p+1)
        MissingModes(p) = TotModLis2(m)
        p = p + 1
    End If
Next 'i
'This section adds equipment records based on the list of missing modes
newequips = "SELECT * FROM Equipment"
rstFleet.Open newequips, conn, 3, 3 
For Each x in MissingModes
rstFleet.Addnew
rstFleet("MemID") = Request("MemID")
rstFleet("modecode") = x
rstFleet.Update
Next
rstFleet.Close
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting exactly ?

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer ? If so, disable friendly error message and you'll get the complete error - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778248(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Doesn't work - I guess our server is set up to display that?

Comment: Could be. Try to browse the page locally from the web server (through remote desktop), I'm pretty sure then you'll get the complete error with stacktrace.

Comment: OK, I guess I will have to figure out how to get the access to do that.  I'm pretty green at this stuff and am not really the manager of our servers or anything.